# How to use private properties in my html-file?

Tags: html, angular, properties, observable

I am trying to show a list of Animals in my html page with their corresponding name and color.
My frontend gets the data from a spring backend that returns a list of Animals.
And I stumbled upon 2 questions that I have:

**1)**
I made the name and color properties private in the Animal class.

Code of the animal class:

```
interface AnimalJson {
  name: string;
  color: string;
}

export class Animal {
  constructor(private name: string, private color: string) {}

  static fromJSON(json: AnimalJson): Animal {
    const a = new Animal(json.name, json.color);
    return a;
  }
}
```

code of my animal-component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DataServiceService } from '../data-service.service';
import { Animal } from '../models/Animal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-animal',
  templateUrl: './animal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./animal.component.css'],
})
export class AnimalComponent implements OnInit {
  public animals: Observable<Animal[]>;

  constructor(private dataService: DataServiceService) {
    this.animals = new Observable<Animal[]>();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.animals = this.dataService.getAnimals();
  }
}
```

code of the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataServiceService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAnimals(): Observable<Animal[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<Animal[]>('http://localhost:8080/animals')
      .pipe(map((animals: any[]): Animal[] => animals.map(Animal.fromJSON)));
  }
}
```

code of the html-page:

```
<div *ngFor="let animal of animals | async">
  <p>{{ animal.name }}</p>
</div>
```

Now when I try to get the animal.name, it gives an error that the name is private so I cant use it in my html page. How should I fix this? Should I just make it public? Or is there something I forget?

**2)**
Is this how you work with observables? Or am I using my observables in a wrong way?

Using the http get methode to get the observable and than call it in my animal-component and use async in my html-file to go over all the values in it?

Comment: Outside of your class file only public properties are accessible.

Comment: with the Angular version 14 you can use protected properties in template, use protected property if you want to keep it in with class but want to use same in template.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `private` then it should not be used in the html, am not sure why you are using a `class` for initializing the array. Just use a simple map statement.

If you are going to show it in the HTML then don't make the property private.

So the changes are.

```
interface Animal {
  name: string;
  color: string;
}
```

Service will be.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataServiceService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAnimals(): Observable<Animal[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<Animal[]>('http://localhost:8080/animals')
      .pipe(map((animals: any[]): Animal[] => animals.map((item: Animal) => ({name: item.name, color: item.color}))));
  }
}
```

Note: class can also be used as an interface, so when using animal you defined the properties as private, so you are unable to use in the HTML.